# Set of numbers evenly distributed between a min and max on log scale

Tags: javascript, math

I have a graph on a log scale with a min and max. I need to specify ticks on this scale. I would like to specify 5 ticks. However, the issue is that I would like the ticks to be evenly distributed. At first naively, I tried this:

```
while (tickValue <= upperTickValue) {
   tickValues.push(
       this.formatNumber.toView(tickValue, 3)
   );
   tickValue = tickValue + interval;
}
```

However, this does not produce evenly spaced ticks on a logarithmic scale (duh).

I need to have a set of numbers that is evenly spaced on the log scale. So, for example, if I was graphing 0.01 to 100, a correct answer would be:

```
[0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have some numbers as data and the wanted result?

Comment: @NinaScholz I updated my OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the nth root of the given values for a scale. Take the `min` and `max` value for preventing floating point errors.

```js
function parts(min, max, scale) {
    var f = Math.pow(max / min, 1 / --scale),
        result = [min];

    while (--scale) {
        result.push(result[result.length - 1] * f);

    }
    result.push(max);
    return result;
}

console.log(parts(0.01, 100, 5));
console.log(parts(4, 5, 5));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```